# What does "Linked in" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, proper-nouns

My guess is that when you have connected to a group, you are "linked in" that group. But then shouldn't the preposition "on" more suitable? I can't find a resource actually says what the company name means, even on its [FAQ](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/1561/company-pages-frequently-asked-questions?lang=en).

[image: Logo for the networking site LinkedIn]

<sup>FYI: [LinkedIn - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn#Discontinued_features)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, **in** is the appropriate preposition.

Membership or participation in a group who are communicating with each other is expressed by **in**.

> Once you're **in** our network, we will direct potential customers to you.

That is, once you join or become a part of our network...

We would use **on** to refer to the communications mechanism or platform itself:

> I haven't been getting any new patients since joining your health-care
>   network.
>   --Are you sure you're properly registered **on** *Health-Link*, our membership portal?

Company-names can also play on associations or connotations.

To be "clued *in*", for example, means to have needed information, to be cognizant of what one should know. To be a part of the "*in*-crowd" means to be belong to a group that many people wish to be belong to.  The word **in** connotes certain *benefits*.

P.S. It is possible to understand a company such as *Linked In* as a communications platform or as a network of  members.  Depending on how the speaker is thinking of it at the moment, the preposition could change.

Comment: How about "to"? And do you know what does "linked in" mean?

Comment: I know what the company Linked-In is, and am familiar with their business model and website.  Please see the part of my answer about company names.  **to** is not a viable preposition here.